# How do I navigate buffers in astrovim?

Tags: neovim

I switch between tabs with `<leader>bb` and typing in the letter that appears on the tab. Is there a faster way? For example, it will switch to a tab to the right / left.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the faster and default Astronvim way is [b and ]b

Answer (score 2):

Set keyboard shortcuts to Tab and Shift+Tab

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<S-Tab>', ':bprev<CR>', { noremap = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<Tab>', ':bnext<CR>', { noremap = true })
```